# Trying to get value within tags: $(this).find(" ").text()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add event to every card which on click will increment counter by 1 to maximum of 3. I want every card to have own counter.

```
$(".bronze").mouseup(function(e){
    if (e.which === 1) {
        var counter = parseInt($(this).find(".bronze_counter").text(), 10)
        if (counter <= 3) {
            counter += 1
        }
    }

});
```

This is my template:

```
<div class="container">
    {% for card in cards %}
        {% if card.type == 'Silver' or card.type == 'Gold' %}
        <span class="gold"><img src="{{ card.thumbnail_link }}" style="width:5%"> [</span><span class="gold_counter">0</span><span>/1] </span>
        {% else %}
        <span class="bronze"><img src="{{ card.thumbnail_link }}" style="width:5%"> [</span><span class="bronze_counter">0</span><span>/3] </span>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Any tips why it doesn't work?

Comment: This is not working at all?? Can you see any errors in console tab of developer console of chrome?

Comment: Describe doesn't work?

Comment: You're increasing the counter, but then you're not doing anything with it...

Comment: Is your jqeury wrapped in a ready statement?

Comment: you should update the html when you increment your counter, something like `$(this).find(".bronze_counter").text(counter);`

Comment: I am getting NaN value, when I do console.log(counter)

Comment: @tomek-a The reason why you get the value `NaN` is that you use `.find()`. `.find()` will search inside the element. You need to search after it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what your looking for.

I've added `alt="bronze"` for the example only.

Since your `".bronze_counter"` is after your `".bronze"` and not a child of it, you have to use `.next()` *

*To prove this look at the HTML below, it will show that it's not a child.

```
<span class="bronze">
    <img src="{{ card.thumbnail_link }}" alt="bronze" style="width:5%">
    [
</span>
<span class="bronze_counter">
    0
</span>
<span>
    /3] 
</span>
```

The reason why you get the value `NaN` is that you use `.find()`. `.find()` will search inside the element.

**working demo**

```js
$(".bronze").click(function(e) {
  if (e.which === 1) {
    var counter = parseInt($(this).next(".bronze_counter").text(), 10)
    console.log(counter)
    if (counter < 3) {
      counter += 1
      $(this).next(".bronze_counter").text(counter)
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <span class="gold"><img src="{{ card.thumbnail_link }}" style="width:5%"> [</span><span class="gold_counter">0</span><span>/1] </span>
  <span class="bronze"><img src="{{ card.thumbnail_link }}" alt="bronze" style="width:5%"> [</span><span class="bronze_counter">0</span><span>/3] </span>
</div>
```